# How can I use inspect elements on Chrome to identify the source of a particular section of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

This may sound like a really stupid question for you guys, but how can I use the inspect elements tool on Chrome to identify the source of a particular section of a website? To make it simpler to understand, I want to modify the footer of a particular website (WordPress based).

The problem is that the footer was customized (which means I can’t edit through the WP backend) so I need to find where exactly or what’s generating this footer.

Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: The footer in wordpress has its own file (footer.php), you can navigate to it by goind to (Appearance > Editor) if you are Admin user.

Comment: He's said he can't do it from the Backend. To be honest, It's bad practice to be making code changes via the dashboard anyway.

Comment: if it is hardcoded (written into the code) then you need to go into the footer.php file and change it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this in Developer tools as wordpress is PHP based, chrome only sees the compile code.

What I would do in your situation is to try searching the theme folder for an ID, Class or piece of code that is unique to the footer and try that way.

Comment: That might actually help. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by visting the website, right clicking and selecting Inspect.

The developer tools dropdown will appear. In the top left corner there is an icon with a pointer hovering over a screen (this is the inspect element tool). Click this, and move your pointer on to the part of the webpage you wish to find the HTML for.

The html for that part of the website will be highlighted in the developer window, making it easy for you to see.

You can then either , edit inline in the browser to get an immediate view of the changed code (this will not be permanent, or change you code file), or use that location, to return to your WP editor and make permanent changes.

Comment: That's where I get a bit lost. I can see the HTML and CSS but the problem is how can I find the location of the file that's generating the footer? 
I mean, what should I be looking at?

`<ul id="menu-copyright-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2634" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2634"><a `

Comment: @DavidMurphy that unfortunately you can't do from the front end. The HTML uses the includes / files to render the HTML page you see on the screen. Once it has been rendered you won't know what includes / files its using to build the footer.

Try looking for footer.php or something.